# Only certain files uploading in PHP (running Docker for Windows)

Tags: php, apache, docker

I'm having issues uploading files from PHP. The odd thing is that some files work and others don't. I can reproduce it with the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

var_dump($_FILES);
```

When it fails, the output is:

```
array(1) {
  ["fileToUpload"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "image_2_3.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(3)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

From what I understand, the error code 3 indicates that it is a partial upload however, I'm not sure why it only occurs for certain files. I can't see a pattern in the files that don't work. For example, one of the files that doesn't work is about 70kb whereas another file that works is 180kb, so it doesn't seem to be a file-size related issue.

I'm running this on a docker container running on Windows 10. The docker image is based on the official [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image. I've tested the tags 5.5-apache and 5.6-apache. The code itself is running from a mounted volume in Windows.

The loaded Apache modules are:

```
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version
mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core
mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex
mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_headers mod_mime prefork
mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

EDIT: Did an isolated test running a plain php:5.5-apache image, with the just PHP code mentioned and am still able to reproduce the issue.

In my last test this file produced the issue: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=14588523736227077930

Whereas this one worked: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03989814485857897493

Comment: Anything in the log files? Is it always the same mimetypes failing? are you only trying image files?

Comment: You'll have to edit the PHP.ini in order to allow it.

Comment: You need to provide more info, what files don't work what filesizes.

Most likely your server is rejecting files above a certain size, then you need to configure in your ini (Or htaccess if it's allowed to allow bigger file sizes + bigger upload size)

Comment: As mentioned, it's not a file size issue as some files that are small work and some larger don't and vice vera. I've tried text files, binary files (exe, xls, jpg, json), etc. I can't see any pattern to what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Could you share any two files; one of which worked, and other didn't. Without inspecting file or you code it's not possible to identify what't the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further digging, I discovered that this is an open issue recently mentioned on the Docker Forums: https://forums.docker.com/t/php-file-upload-fails-with-upload-err-partial-on-docker-for-windows/18252

The current workaround (which I've tested) is to use either `http://docker` or `docker.local` instead of `http://localhost` when accessing the application via the browser.